# Yii Overwrite createUrl but keep parameters

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii, extend

I am extending and overwriting the createUrl method to make pretty URLs.

Here is a snippet:

```
public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params, $ampersand) {
        if($route == 'widget/view'){
            $widget = Widget::model()->findByPk($params['id']);
            return 'widget/' . $params['id'] . '/' . SEOUrlRule::slug($widget->title);
        }
}
```

Lots of things don't matter much here. And I removed irrelevant parts.

It works fine. However, sometimes the method may be called with additional parameters such as an anchor tag, or GET parameters to put at the end of the URL.

Using my method, these parameters will be lost. To pass them forward in the new URL, do I have to re-do whatever the original createUrl method did manually? Or is there a nice object oriented way to pass the job along to a competent method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made every argument required - is that intentional?

You can have Yii construct the parameter string by using the createUrl from CApplication, e.g.:

```
public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params, $ampersand) { 
        if($route == 'widget/view'){
            $widget = Widget::model()->findByPk($params['id']);
            $url = 'widget/' . $params['id'] . '/' . SEOUrlRule::slug($widget->title);
            return Yii::app()->createUrl(trim($url,'/'),$params,$ampersand);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I am trying to achieve. The original createUrl method adds parameters and anchor tags at the end of URLs if necessary. The problem is when I return a manually written URL (return widget...) it won't add those at the end of the URL